# directly initialize a shared_ptr on class construction

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm playing with the c++11 pointers and I don't understand why this use of the shared_ptr isnt allowed.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> i{ std::make_shared<int>(1) };
```

I'm getting `The function is declared 'noexcept' but calls function 'make_shared<int,int>' which may throw exceptions(f.6)`

If I put it in my constructor, which is also noexcept, it is also not accepted obviously.

```
JobLogger() noexcept { 
    this->i = std::make_shared<int>();
}
```

In the shared_ptr source I can see that the empty constructor is noexcept `constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept {}`, so how should I initialize `i` on construction of JobLogger?

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that you're trying to do allocation, and allocation might throw, but your function is `noexcept`. If you want this to be allowed, you have to catch the exception and do something else about the failure. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?  I cannot reproduce: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43e72490c96fb8d3

Comment: *In the shared_ptr source I can see that the empty constructor is noexcept* -- Are you looking at `std::make_shared`?  Just declaring a shared_ptr will not allocate memory.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no I'm looking at shared_ptr (visual studio -> f12)

Comment: Then you're looking in the wrong place.  You're calling `make_shared`, not merely declaring a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Brian I want `i` to be initialized on class initialization. Google on C26495

Comment: But what do you want to initialize it to? If your initialization requires allocation, then you need a plan for what to do when allocation fails. Or are you ok with leaving it null?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know, but is try catching in the constructor like Brian suggests really the only option?

Comment: If you want the failed allocation to be propagated up the call stack to a context that knows what to do about it, then you shouldn't mark your function `noexcept`. `noexcept` explicitly *disables* that propagation mechanism.

Comment: I am pretty sure that first line also fails to compile because your default constructor is noexcept, since the make_shared<> is executed **as part of the construction**. The simple truth is that if you want to call make_shared as part of JobLogger's construction, then you need to catch and handle that potential exception, or not make it noexcept in the first place.

Comment: @Brian so the warning about make_shared could be ignored? About what I  try to do: Basically Im trying to use a shared pointer instead of `int* i{ new int() };`

Comment: @Frank, I can build, but it will show the message about the noexcept C26447

Comment: Again: If you want to allocate in the constructor, either by directly calling `new` or indirectly through `std::make_shared`, then you need to decide what should happen when that allocation fails. By marking your constructor `noexcept`, you are basically saying "when allocation fails, I want the program to crash". If you want to do something other than that, you have to tell us, otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: As an aside, that's not how you initialize member variables in a constructor. You should be doing `JobLogger() : i(std::make_shared<int>()) { }`. If you want to add `try`/`catch` on that you'd write `JobLogger() try : i(std::make_shared<int>()) { } catch(...) { /* etc */ }`.

Comment: @Brian the code before was with `new` like my previous comment. That wasn't catched as well. I guess thats where part of my confusion comes from why that would not give a warning. I mean, I understand you're right and I should try catch the assignment.

Comment: @HTNW Ill try this too, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @GertKommer Do note that just catching the error is not going to be enough. After that, every single public method of `JobLogger` needs to account for the fact that `i` can be potentially null, since you will have fundamentally changed the class' invariant. Otherwise, catching and handling the error will have meant nothing, and you will have just deferred the crash to later in the program.

Comment: @NathanOliver These messages are because of the "C++ Core Guidelines checker"